Concerning the definition of a class of functions introduced by Nilsson
In the paper 'Some growth and ramification properties of certain integrals on algebraic manifolds' by Nilsson we find the following definitions:

My question is how does one prove the remark "It may be proved that the condition (c) is not changed if we only permit
pairs $(n_1, n_2)$ of the form $(n_1, 1)$."?
Many thanks.
